# Comparing from textbox to database

Tags: php

Please help me. I'm having trouble in comparing
How do I compare the quantity that was inserted from the stocks from the database

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("config.php");

//empty cart by distroying current session
if(isset($_GET["emptycart"]) && $_GET["emptycart"]==1)
{
    $return_url = base64_decode($_GET["return_url"]); //return url
    session_destroy();
    header('Location:'.$return_url);
}

//add item in shopping cart
if(isset($_POST["type"]) && $_POST["type"]=='add')
{
    $product_code   = filter_var($_POST["product_code"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //product code
    $product_qty    = filter_var($_POST["product_qty"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); //product code
    $return_url     = base64_decode($_POST["return_url"]); //return url
    $sel = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products");
    $product_stock = mysql_fetch_assoc($sel);
    //limit quantity for single product
    if($product_qty > $products['stock'])
    {
        die('<div align="center">Not enought quantity<br /><a href="index.php">Back To Products</a>.</div>');
    }
```

Comment: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\webdev\prac\php-shopping-cart-sample-815061\cart_update.php on line 20

Comment: try `$sel = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products") or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: It says no database selected

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in this line:

```
if($product_qty > $products['stock'])
```

What is `$products['stock']`? Above you defined the MySQL result like that:

```
$product_stock = mysql_fetch_assoc($sel);
```

So, did you mean?

```
if($product_qty > $product_stock['stock'])
```

Also, your code is vulnerable to redirection-attacks: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A10-Unvalidated_Redirects_and_Forwards

You need to make sure that you somehow validate the parameter `return_url`, by allowing only a valid list of URLs. Better would be:

```
$valid_urls = array(1 => 'http://link1.com', 2 => '...');
```

And then:

```
$return_url_param = (int)$_GET["return_url"];
$return_url = isset($valid_urls[$return_url_param] ? $valid_urls[$return_url_param] : 'http://defaulturl.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing `$product_qty` from wrong variable . Try change `$products['stock']` to `$product_stock['stock']`.

Corrected block of code:-

```
<?php

//add item in shopping cart
if (isset($_POST["type"]) && $_POST["type"] == 'add') {
    $product_code = filter_var($_POST["product_code"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //product code
    $product_qty = filter_var($_POST["product_qty"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); //product code
    $return_url = base64_decode($_POST["return_url"]); //return url
    $sel = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products");
    $product_stock = mysql_fetch_assoc($sel);
    //limit quantity for single product
    if ($product_qty > $product_stock['stock']) {
        die('<div align="center">Not enought quantity<br /><a href="index.php">Back To Products</a>.</div>');
    }
}
```